# How to do "Lazy-write" per-request logging in Django?

Tags: django

Using Django, I need to do some per-request logging that involves database writes.

I understand Django's `process_request()` and `process_response()` middleware hooks, but as far as I can tell, those hooks are in the critical path (by design) for rendering the Web page response.

I'd prefer not to have my post-request database write operations holding up the response time for the page.

Is there a simple design pattern for Django that lets me do a "lazy log write", where I can use request hooks to gather information during request processing, but any follow-on operations and the actual log write operation does not occur until after the response is written to the user?

I'm using WSGI currently, but would prefer the most general solution possible.

Comment: One alternative is to use a logging.Handler that buffers the writes. Maybe give it a flush() so that you can tell it when to write to the "real" handler.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/4313508/621690

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django implements a [`request_finished`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_finished)-signal which is fired after the processing of the response has been finished, but the down side is, it will not allow you to access the current `request` object which makes it not quite useful for logging... The latest place to hook into django's response processing is most probably in the [HttpResponse class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313508/execute-code-in-django-after-response-has-been-sent-to-the-client/4314182#4314182). You could eg. store the data temporarily in `request.session` and write them to the database in the `close()` method.

But I guess there are also other alternatives you should consider: You could use something like [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) to handle your logging tasks asynchronously. Furthermore there are non-sql databases like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) that offer you handy and performant features for logging, eg. [you dont have to wait until the changes are really committed](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging) to the database which can give you a big performance advantage.

Comment: Signals are actually executed in-process, but +1 for Celery as an asynchronous solution.

Comment: Well you're right, looked it up in the code base, the signal is sent before the response is returned by the WSGI handler, though the signal's name might suggest something else. For everybody interested: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L275