# Django Rest Framework: specify a callback method when defining an endpoint?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I was asking myself if there is a simple way of defining a callback method when defining a DRF endpoint.

For example, let's say I want to reproduce this workflow:

- app1 sends data to app2, calling a DRF endpoint living in app2
- app2 immediately sends the HTTP 200/201 response to app1
- app2 makes a "heavy" work then.

Of course, I'm aware there are cleaner alternative:

- I know heavy work loads should live in a Celery task, or Django channel
- I know it would make more sense in my case that app2 is the one that makes the request, and app1 sends the response.

I found ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313508/execute-code-in-django-after-response-has-been-sent-to-the-client) but it's very related to Django itself, not Django Rest Framework.

Comment: What's the question? You already are aware that celery type of workers would be needed for async calls.

Comment: Are you aware of Django Channels? https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

Comment: Here's an alternative to Celery: https://github.com/Koed00/django-q

Comment: Yes I know all of these solutions. But the purpose of my question is *NOT* to find an additional tool to fulfill my need. I just want to know how to do it without any tool, even if it's not elegant. Please take a look at the link I provided, I'm looking for a similar solution, but DRF related.

Answer (score 1):

Use Celery for async tasks. Anyway, you can launch a thread in a Django view and run async functions:

```
import logging
import threading
from time import sleep
from django.shortcuts import render

def print_async():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i, '...')
        sleep(1)

def your_view(request, template_name="home.html"):
    # ...
    t = threading.Thread(target=print_async)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    # ...
    return render(request, template_name, {})
```